# Power BI Query Editor - problem adding new calculated column using Text.AfterDelimiter - Token EOF Expected

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I received some great guidance from a couple of people yesterday - I'm now struggling with adding their suggestions into the Query Editor when adding a new column.

```
"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "QID", each 
        Text.Trim(
            Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition({"0".."9"}, (c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c))
                (Text.AfterDelimiter([Short description],"IDN")){0}), type text)
in
    "Added Custom"
```

I get the error: Token EOF Expected.

This is what it looks like in the editor:

[image: PBI Error]

Can anyone see what may be wrong with what I've entered?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: Integrate that using the Advanced Editor.

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean - is the Query Editor not the advanced editor? Thanks

Comment: see answer I just posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're trying to integrate a snippet of M into an existing query, use the Advanced Editor.

[image]